# How to detect if Chromecast is already connected on Android Sender?

Tags: android, google-cast

I have an Android sender for Google Cast, and a Chromecast. I can cast video to a TV, and the cast button on actionbar becomes white.

Now comes the question. When I leave the sender app, Chromecast continues to play video. This is what I want. But when I re-open the sender app, I don't know how to detect if the devices is already running my receiver, so I need to automatically join current session.

Can anyone help? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`joinApplication()` has three different variations; in one of them, you can specify an `applicationId` and join happens successfully only if the cast device is running that application.

If you want to join when not only the same app is running, but also still in the same session that you had started before, you need to persist the `sessionId` each time you launch an app and then use another variation of the `joinApplication()` that takes an `applicationId` and a `sessionId`.

Comment: I also need to get the playing `CastDevice` when building `GoogleApiClient`. Since `onRouteSelected` is not called, I need another way. Is there some callbacks can be used?

Comment: What is the use case?

Comment: 1. Open sender app
2. Cast, sender app changes UI for controlling Chromecast
3. Use back button to exit app
4. User re-open sender app
At this time, I want the sender app automatically changes UI for controlling Chromecast, so I need to know if the devices is running receiver of this sender app.

Comment: Look at the implementation of the method reconnectSessionIfPossible() here: https://github.com/googlecast/CastCompanionLibrary-android/blob/master/src/com/google/sample/castcompanionlibrary/cast/BaseCastManager.java#L815